# Losing GET variable on form submit or on refresh

Tags: php, session-variables

I am sending an id from a link

```
<a class="suba" href="empty.php?id=1" ></a>
```

and recieving this id in the empty.php page :

```
require_once 'connection.php';
session_start();

$id=$_GET['id'];
```

on refresh or on form submit the variable $id is lost :

```
  <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="next">
            </form>
  <?php  if(isset($_GET['add']) && $_SESSION['j'] < $filecount){
         $_SESSION['j']++;
         echo '<input type=hidden name=id value=' .$id. '>';

    } ?>
```

I tried adding a hidden input in the form but it's not working also tried saving the variable in a session:

```
$_SESSION["word"] = $id;
```

Comment: Write your hidden field inside form tag!!

Comment: I don't see how the value could be lost on refresh unless you do a redirect somewhere or use javascript to manipulate the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You must print the Id in your form action

```
 <form action="?id=<?= $id ?>" method="get">
   <input type="submit" name="add" value="next">
 </form>
```

Comment: The form won't ever submitted correctly since its action is pointed to undefined script file.

Comment: Adding action="<?= $id ?> " redirected me into a empty page and an error appeared OBJECT NOT FOUND @Kalit

Comment: Oh sorry, realy i wrote this wrong :) now i edited post and should work better